# Sagemaker default inference handler initializes with 'None' transformer

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Executing inference with default mxnet serving container. No updates made to entrypoint script. Inference fails while trying to initialize transformer in service handler https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-mxnet-serving-container/blob/44fe1e4cbbde32a0126426fedf176351ab3dfc20/src/sagemaker_mxnet_serving_container/handler_service.py#L46

Description:
Converted a gluon cv video model to Symbolic format and exported to model directory with params,symbol and shapes file. Deployed this endpoint to SM and then ran inference. See this error:

```
W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_inference/default_handler_service.py", line 50, in handle
W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle -     return self._service.transform(data, context)
W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transform'
```

Code:

```py
model_name = 'i3d_resnet50_v1_kinetics400'

net = get_model(model_name, nclass=400, pretrained=True)

print('%s model is successfully loaded.' % model_name)

net.hybridize()

'#Predict output for 1 video clip to initialize the model before export'

x = nd.array(clip_input)

y = net.forward(x)

print(y) #this works fine

net.export(model_name)
```

Refer : https://medium.com/@julsimon/quick-tip-converting-gluon-models-to-symbolic-format-9513e5dd1d73

```py
'#then tar the model directory with params,shape and symbol'

sagemaker_model = MXNetModel(model_data = 's3://' + sagemaker_session.default_bucket() + '/model/model.tar.gz',
                                  role = role,framework_version='1.6.0',py_version='py3',entry_point='dummy.py')

predictor = sagemaker_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
                                          instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')
```

Inference call: content type = npy

Comment: can you include your code for deploying the endpoint?

Comment: updated with code